# How to call javascript extended (overrided?) function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extend kendo.ui.validator (similar to jQuery validator)
I am overriding the date function, but I should overload the mvcdate function with the very same logic. The overrided date function is called and runs correctly.

I would not like to copy and paste so trying to call the overrided data function from the mvcdata override, with no success. The syntax is `this.rules.date(input)` I am totally beginner in javascript OOP part so I have no idea what I am doing, although my syntax seems to be reasonable. What am I missing?

```
(function ($, kendo) {
    $.extend(true, kendo.ui.validator, {
        rules: {
            date: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[data-val-date]")) {
                    var value = input.val();
                    var check = false;
                    //var m = moment(value.toString(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", true);
                    var m = moment(value.toString(), defaultJavaScriptDateFormat, true);
                    check = m.isValid();
                    //var message = "";
                    //if (!check) {
                    //    message = "Invalid " + m.invalidAt() + ". Please enter a correct date";
                    //}
                    //input.attr("data-val-date", message);
                    return !input.is("[data-val-required]") || check;
                }
                return true;
            },
            mvcdate: function (input) {
                // Here I try to call the overrided date function to prevent copy and paste, this cause runtime error in chrome:
                return this.rules.date(input);
            }
        },
        messages: {
            date: function (input) {
                return input.attr("data-val-date");
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery, kendo);
```

Comment: have you tried `this.date(input)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your function using direct method call:

```
mvcdate: function (input) {
    return kendo.ui.validator.rules.date.call(this, input);
}
```

If `kendo.ui.validator` is an instance of an object created using `new` keyword and your `date` function is the part of prototype you can call it using prototype:

```
mvcdate: function (input) {
    return kendo.ui.validator.prototype.rules.date.call(this, input);
}
```

Comment: return kendo.ui.validator.rules.date.call(this, input) is working thx.